# Bootstrap modal not closing properly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have a button that when I click it, it is supposed to close a bootstrap modal. if I use
 `data-dismiss="modal"` 
on the button my server side click event does not fire. when I instead use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "success", "$('#myTreatmentModal').modal('hide');", true);`

The modal goes away and my server side code fires but the darkened background put on the body by the modal does not get removed.

If you have any suggestions as to what I should do I'd definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hiding the backdrop too, this a Javascript function that hides the modal by its id and then hides the global modal backdrop.

```
function hideModal(id) {
  $("#" + id).modal("hide");
  $(".modal-backdrop").hide();
}
```

Call it from the aspx:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "success", "hideModal('myTreatmentModal');", true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It works however the page is left unresponsive when the modal closes and I am unsure why

Comment: i figured it out. I had to also remove modal-open from the body tag. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.noConflict(); before model hide may be this happened due to jquery conflict

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have made any difference